# Cast to Array of composed parameter types

Tags: java

To create an array of parameter types there is 2 ways:

- cast from new Object[] in creation.
- create Object[] and cast each time at pushing or retrieving.

create Object[] and cast each time.

A want to create a generic class:

```
public class Element<K, V> {

private K key;
private V value;
private Element<K, V> next;
// Getters and Setters
}
```

and create an array of Element.
While the second solution works fine:

```
public class HashTable<K, V> {

private final int ARRAY_SIZE = 7;

private Object [] holder;


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public HashTable() {
    holder =  new Object[ARRAY_SIZE];
}

void push(K key, V value) {
    //Some code
    Element<K, V> element = (Element<K, V>)holder[index];
    // Some code
}

public V getValue(K key) {
//some code
Element<K, V> e = (Element<K, V>)holder[index];
// Some code
}
}
```

I get the error Cannot cast from Object[] to Element, when i try the first solution:

```
private Element<K, V> holder;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public HashTable() {
    holder = (Element[]) new Object[ARRAY_SIZE]; //ERROR
}
```

Comment: You have to cast to array (Element[])

Comment: @Worthless yes even though i get: java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to interview/[Larraysandstring.Element;

Comment: @azro can't create array of generics though

Comment: Is there a reason why you especially need to use an array? You could use an `ArrayList<Element<K, V>>` instead of an array. Because of historical and backward compatibility reasons, generics and arrays don't work well together in Java.

Comment: @Jesper i agree with you, but just for the culture, is there a way to achieve it or it's impossible.

Comment: What you're asking can't be done the second way. An Object[] could already be holding, for a simple example, a Long in slot 0 and a Double in slot 1. Neither can be cast to an Element. To cast an array, the base types must be compatible.